# SQL Azure Federation and EF Code First Database Generation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to use EF Code First Database Generation in a federated SQL Azure database? I don't want to manually create my schema after having just created my objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/10/sql-azure-federations-and-the-entity-framework.aspx) on ADO.NET team blog, it is not possible:

> The current release of Entity Framework can be used to work with SQL
>   Azure Federations, however a federated database cannot be created by
>   the Entity Framework.

You can also check referenced start guide for EF used with SQL Azure Federation.

Comment: Thanks for the apparently correct but extremely disappointing answer. :-/

Comment: Is this still a valid answer. I'm looking for a way to get started with EF Code first and Azure federations.